# How can I use Jack for all my system sounds?

Tags: sound, jack, firewire

I have a firewire soundcard (Phonic FireFly808 [not the "808-U" version!]) which I would like to use as my standard soundcard. From what I found out, it seems like only ffado could get this firewire card running. ffado only runs with jack, so I installed jack (which I wanted to use for realtime audio anyway).
Now I can play sound via jack.

The next step would be to redirect all system sounds and the sound output of all applications to run through jackd. I searched the web for audio bridges, but I'm not even sure what sound system is used by Ubuntu 11.10 (which I re-installed 20min ago). There is Alsa, Pulseaudio, OSS and millions more and I'm lacking knowledge about the topic.

So after this long story my short question: 
**How can I use jack for all my system sounds?**

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu uses PulseAudio for the default audio.

For info in intergrating with JACK:

- http://jackaudio.org/faq/pulseaudio_and_jack.html
- http://trac.jackaudio.org/wiki/WalkThrough/User/PulseOnJack

Comment: Updated instruction here https://github.com/jackaudio/jackaudio.github.com/wiki/WalkThrough_User_PulseOnJack

Comment: Link-only answer, second link is invalid. Please elaborate this answer and include the essential details in your answer, leave links only as a reference. Readers shouldn't have to open third party websites to get the answer to the question.