# Using Jack audio and getting audio to play though headphones

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, jack

I need to use Jack audio to prevent clicks but I'm having problems getting jack to play though my usb wireless g930 headphones.

I'm using puredata and I can get my usb wireless g930 headphones to work with the Alsa setting but Jack will only play through the speakers.  Does anyone know how I can get jack to play through my headphones?

Thanks

PS I'm using ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use jack and pulseaudio together. 
Here's what needs to be installed along with a youtube video

```
1) sudo apt-get pulseaudio-module-jack
2) sudo gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa
add lines load-module module-jack-sink and
load-module module-jack-source
```

See video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6J-RQudJx30

Answer (score 2):

This was tested to work with ubuntu 12.04 Host and ubuntu 10.04 guest.
in virtualbox 4.1.22

1) launch pulseaudio volume control in your host system.
2) launch your virtualbox guest OS (ubuntu 10.04)

3) change setting to logitech g930 view second image

[image]

[image]